# Mongoid rails, attribute.downcase when building index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, mongoid

The behavior I am trying to achieve is doing a case-insensitive sort of all documents in a collection.

My understanding is that there is not a quick way to do this with mongoid and so adding it to the index is one options.

I have a model 'Tag', which has an attribute 'name'

What I am attempting to do is index the lowercased version of 'name'

I was hoping I could do something like;
  index({:name.downcase => 1}, {name: 'lcase_name'})

But it didn't work.

Is it possible to define the indexing of an attribute in a block statement?

Something like;
index do |attribute|
blah blah
end

Anyways, the only solution I have found thus far is to create another attribute on the model 'Tag' which is set with a before save call back 'Tag.lcase_name = Tag.name.downcase' and then index the new attribute.

This of course works, but I would love to just take care of all this in the index for the model instead of creating another attribute on the model.

Comment: Extra attributes is how I've always gotten around MongoDB's server-side limitations.

Comment: For anyone who is interested, I later realized that ruby's Sort method could perform the downcase and comparison that I was looking for.